# sqlite3 select query hang in IOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite

I can receive the data from .sql file(sqlite) in iOS5 , But in ios6. The app is getting hang..

If the query is `select * from Table` then works perfectly

If query is `select *from Table order by ID DESC` then the app is getting hang

some times the app hang in `(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String],&db) == SQLITE_OK)`

some times hangs in

```
while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
}
```

Comment: prefer to use core data in place of sql statements

Comment: can you paste your entire code here?

Comment: i mean the app is hang in "sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW" - this line..

Comment: How much data is there in your table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalize the statements and Close the connection properly each you perform an operation, then you should be fine with the sqlite. If the statements are not finalized then you get to states like SQLITE_BUSY,SQLITE_LOCKED which you need to handle. If the app is hanging that means your main thread is blocked. Following is a sample sqlite operation.

```
-(int)keyIdForImgId:(int)ImgId
{

    @synchronized(self)
    {
        int keyId=0;

        sqlite3 *database=nil;
        if (sqlite3_open([[self getDBPath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

            const char *sql = "SELECT keyId From SomeTableName WHERE imageId=?";
            sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt=nil;
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

                sqlite3_bind_int(selectstmt, 1, ImgId);

                while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
                {

                    keyId = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);


                }

            }
            sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
            sqlite3_close(database);
        }
        return keyId;

    }
}
```

Comment: I have an app which is using sqlite and it is running well in iOS 6 also, I am doing all the sqlite operations on main thread. my be you have too many threads trying to establish the db connection at a time.

Comment: "select *from Table order by ID DESC" is not working, But "select *from Table" is working